# interface type check: direct assignment fails, indirect works

Tags: typescript

I have trouble understanding, why a direct assignment of an object literal to a variable (typed to an interface) fails, but the indirect assignment of the exact same object type checks.

Consider the following example:

```
interface User { name: string }

// vs code complains: "only specify known properties"
const usr1 : User = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 42   // <- squiggly red line
}

// works
const usr2 : User = usr1;
```

Both `usr1` and `usr2` are typed to `User`, both recieve the same value. Why does visual studio code only complain about the first?
Is it an IDE issue or a TypeScript concept that I am not understanding?

### To elaborate a bit

Consider the expanded example:

```
interface User { name: string }

// doesn't work
// const usr1 : User = {
//   name: 'John',
//   age: 42   // <- squiggly red line
// }

// assignment works obviously because usr3 is not typed to User
const usr3 = {
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 33
}

// works
const usr2 : User = usr3;


const getName = (u: User) => console.log(u.name);

getName(usr2);                       // works!
getName({ name: 'Jane', age: 33 });  // doesn't work!
```

This is confusing! The formal parameter `u` of `getName()` recieves the exact same value. First time it works, second it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.

Getting around these checks is actually really simple. The easiest method is to just use a type assertion:

```
let mySquare = createSquare({ width: 100, opacity: 0.5 } as SquareConfig);
```

However, a better approach might be to add a string index signature if you’re sure that the object can have some extra properties that are used in some special way. If SquareConfig can have color and width properties with the above types, but could also have any number of other properties, then we could define it like so:

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
    [propName: string]: any;
}
```

here we’re saying a SquareConfig can have any number of properties, and as long as they aren’t color or width, their types don’t matter.

One final way to get around these checks, which might be a bit surprising, is to assign the object to another variable: Since squareOptions won’t undergo excess property checks, the compiler won’t give you an error.

```
let squareOptions = { colour: "red", width: 100 };
let mySquare = createSquare(squareOptions);
```

(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html, subtitle "Excess Property Checks")

Comment: Getting around these checks is not the goal, it's rather the opposite. I want TypeScript to complain whenever an object has an unknown property, not only when I'm passing an object literal. Regarding my code snippet: I don't want the line `const usr2 : User = usr3;` to work.

Comment: @TerenceS. then add a type annotation to usr3 definition

`const usr3: User = {name: 'Jane', age: 33}`

Comment: @TerenceS. `const usr2 : User = usr3;` is possible because of the structural typing. With the excess property checks, the TypeScript team made the hypothesis that when you’re declaring explicitly an object of a specific type, you probably don’t want to have extra properties. 
You can look at Flow. Flow lacks extra properties check by default. But Flow offers sealed types, which are types that cannot have extra properties.

Comment: The problem is, in the real code base, I don't get to use object literals. Those objects are already created and assigned to variables constants / arrays. So apparently I can't rely on the type system to weed out the the objects with 'too many' properties because `function myFuntion(x: MyInterface) { ... }` will happily accept all of them if they have at least the props matching the interface. Thanks anyways for your detailed answer. Yes maybe I will look into Flow.